# How I can pause a line of code in python without pausing all of the script?

Tags: python, kivy

I want to delay a function in the code, but not all the script, because if I do so the countdown animation stops playing because when you use time.sleep() function if puts in sleep all the app. So I ask if there is a way to delay only a function or a line of code that executes the photo function?

This is my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import Video
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import datetime
import time
import threading

class MyPhotoBoothApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global fl
        fl = FloatLayout()
        fl = FloatLayout(size=(300, 300))
        global buttonstart
        buttonstart = Button(text=' ', background_color=[0, 0, 0, 0], on_press=self.startcycle)
        fl.add_widget(buttonstart)
        global videostart
        videostart = Video(source='C:/PhotoBooth/animations/Start/TouchHereToStart.mov',  state='play', options={'allow_stretch': False})
        videostart.options = {'eos': 'loop'}
        fl.add_widget(videostart)
        return fl

    def startcycle(self, *arg):
        fl.remove_widget(buttonstart)
        fl.remove_widget(videostart)
        self.countdown = Video(source='C:/PhotoBooth/animations/Countdown/Countdown.mov',  state='play', options={'allow_stretch': False})
        self.countdown.options = {'eos': 'false'}
        countdowntimer = threading.Thread(target=self.countdown)
        fl.add_widget(self.countdown)
        #self.takephoto()
        return fl

    def takephoto(self, *arg):
        countdowntimer.join()
        print("DONE")
        def func_TakeNikonPicture(input_filename):
            camera_command = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\digiCamControl\CameraControlCmd.exe'
            camera_command_details = '/filename C:testing/' + input_filename + ' /capturenoaf'
            full_command=camera_command + ' ' + camera_command_details
            p = subprocess.Popen(full_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True, shell=False)


        if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
            rawimagename = 'photo.jpg'
        else:   

            files = sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)]

            rawimagename = files[0]
            if(os.path.isfile(rawimagename) is True):
                print("Image saved")
                sys.exit()


        current_dt=datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
        rawimagename=current_dt + '_' + rawimagename

        func_TakeNikonPicture(rawimagename)

    #func_TakeNikonPicture(rawimagename)

Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'auto')
Config.set('graphics', 'window_state', 'maximized')
Config.set('graphics', 'rotation', 0)
MyPhotoBoothApp().run()
```

Comment: Don't use time.sleep, schedule a new function to be called after the period you want to wait for.

Comment: which line ? All depends how it is used.

Comment: As @inclement says, use `Clock.schedule_once()`.